# JavaScript validation of radio buttons

Tags: javascript

Below it's a quiz built with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and it has 4 questions and I want to make radio buttons of questions to be selected otherwise it will show an alert saying "Please check an option", but it does not work and I can skip questions by pressing button "Next" and leaving options empty.
Any idea how this can be solved?

```js
let question1 = document.getElementById('pytja1');
let question2 = document.getElementById('pytja2');
let question3 = document.getElementById('pytja3');
let question4 = document.getElementById('pytja4');
let result = document.getElementById('bot-submit');
let nextButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.bot');

for (let i = 0; i < nextButtons.length; i++) {
  let nextQuestion = nextButtons[i];
  nextQuestion.onclick = function() {
    switchToNextQuestion(this);
  };
}

function switchToNextQuestion(nextQuestion) {
  let parentId = nextQuestion.parentNode.id;
  if (parentId === 'pytja1') {
    question1.style.display = 'none';
    question2.style.display = 'block';
  } else if (parentId === 'pytja2') {
    question2.style.display = 'none';
    question3.style.display = 'block';
  } else if (parentId === 'pytja3') {
    question3.style.display = 'none';
    question4.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function validateForm() {
    let radios = document.getElementsByName("q1");
    let formValid = false;

    let i = 0;
    while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
        if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
        i++;        
    }
    if (!formValid) alert("Select one option");
    return formValid;
}
```

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.quiz {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 42%;
}

.quest1,
.quest2,
.quest3,
.quest4 {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.questions1 {
  margin-left: 28px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.questions2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.questions3 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.questions4 {
  background-color: olivedrab;
}

.bot {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#pytja2,
#pytja3,
#pytja4 {
  margin-left: 28px;
  display: none;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "results">
      <form id="quiz-form">
          <div class="quiz">
            <div id="pytja1" class="questions1">
              <span class="quest1">I am a ?</span><br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q1" value="male" id="correct"> Male<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q1" value="female" id="correct2"> Female<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q1" value="other" id="correct3"> Other<br/>
              <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" onclick="return validateForm()"/>
            </div>
            <div id="pytja2" class="questions2">
              <span class="quest2">Football has letters ?</span><br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q2" value="8" class="correct"> 8<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q2" value="5"> 5<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q2" value="6"> 6<br/>
              <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" />
            </div>
            <div id="pytja3" class="questions3">
              <span class="quest3">VW stands for ?</span><br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q3" value="BMW" /> BMW <br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q3" value="Volkswagen" class="correct" /> Volkswagen<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q3" value="Audi" /> Audi<br/>
              <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" />
            </div>
            <div id="pytja4" class="questions4">
              <span class="quest4">What year it is ?</span><br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q4" value="2017" /> 2017<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q4" value="2015" /> 2015<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q4" value="2019" class="correct" /> 2019<br/>
              <input id="bot-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by calling your `validateForm()` function within the click event handler of your **next** buttons. This function is returning a boolean, if it's true, call `switchToNextQuestion()`.

To be able to do this we need to make some slight modifications to your code though.

```
for (let i = 0; i < nextButtons.length; i++) {
  let nextQuestion = nextButtons[i];
  nextQuestion.onclick = function() {

    if (validateForm(i + 1)) {
      switchToNextQuestion(this);
    }
  };
}
```

Here we're calling validateForm using a newly parameter, which tells the function wich input dialog to validate.

The modified validateForm function:

```
function validateForm(elementNumber) {
  let radios = document.getElementsByName("q" + elementNumber);
  let formValid = false;
  let i = 0;
  while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
    if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
    i++;
  }
  if (!formValid) alert("Select one option");
  return formValid;
}
```

Finally a working example:

```js
let question1 = document.getElementById('pytja1');
let question2 = document.getElementById('pytja2');
let question3 = document.getElementById('pytja3');
let question4 = document.getElementById('pytja4');
let result = document.getElementById('bot-submit');
let nextButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.bot');

for (let i = 0; i < nextButtons.length; i++) {
  let nextQuestion = nextButtons[i];
  nextQuestion.onclick = function() {

    if (validateForm(i + 1)) {
      switchToNextQuestion(this);
    }
  };
}

function switchToNextQuestion(nextQuestion) {
  let parentId = nextQuestion.parentNode.id;
  if (parentId === 'pytja1') {
    question1.style.display = 'none';
    question2.style.display = 'block';
  } else if (parentId === 'pytja2') {
    question2.style.display = 'none';
    question3.style.display = 'block';
  } else if (parentId === 'pytja3') {
    question3.style.display = 'none';
    question4.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function validateForm(elementNumber) {
  let radios = document.getElementsByName("q" + elementNumber);
  let formValid = false;
  let i = 0;
  while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
    if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
    i++;
  }
  if (!formValid) alert("Select one option");
  return formValid;
}
```

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.quiz {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 42%;
}

.quest1,
.quest2,
.quest3,
.quest4 {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.questions1 {
  margin-left: 28px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.questions2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.questions3 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.questions4 {
  background-color: olivedrab;
}

.bot {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#pytja2,
#pytja3,
#pytja4 {
  margin-left: 28px;
  display: none;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="results">
  <form id="quiz-form">
    <div class="quiz">
      <div id="pytja1" class="questions1">
        <span class="quest1">I am a ?</span><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="male" id="correct"> Male<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="female" id="correct2"> Female<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="other" id="correct3"> Other<br/>
        <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" />
      </div>
      <div id="pytja2" class="questions2">
        <span class="quest2">Football has letters ?</span><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="8" class="correct"> 8<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="5"> 5<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="6"> 6<br/>
        <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" />
      </div>
      <div id="pytja3" class="questions3">
        <span class="quest3">VW stands for ?</span><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="BMW" /> BMW <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="Volkswagen" class="correct" /> Volkswagen<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="Audi" /> Audi<br/>
        <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" />
      </div>
      <div id="pytja4" class="questions4">
        <span class="quest4">What year it is ?</span><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q4" value="2017" /> 2017<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q4" value="2015" /> 2015<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q4" value="2019" class="correct" /> 2019<br/>
        <input id="bot-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help man :)
And i have a question why you added "elementNumber" to the "function validateForm()" ?

Comment: You're welcome! :) You have given the radio buttons of a specific question a name like "q1" for the first question, "q2" for the second... By telling validateForm which question is currently visible we can determine which radio buttons to validate.

Comment: @obsecure - Oh got it now and changed the name of "q2,q3,q4", to all "q1" and removed elementNumber and it works still, never knew about elementNumber and learned it by you thank you :)
And the last question if you clear for me about this "if (validateForm(i + 1)) {
      switchToNextQuestion(this);
    }", "i" it's for increment got it, but about number 1 why you added there ?

Comment: Because we're looping over an array `let nextButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.bot');` (which starts at 0) and you numbered your elements from 1 onwards. ;)

Comment: oh I had querySelector  I see now :) Thank you again for fixing for me because I was stuck for 1 week with this quiz and had no idea how to solve, thank again :)

Comment: hey @obscure - I need again a little help if you can help me with my submit button, Below on Codepen is the same quiz just now I have added some new lines in JS page for quiz to show me how many questions I got correct when I finish the quiz, but there's a problem that it shows always "Your score is 0/4" and when I try to click submit button even if I choose an option it says 4 times an alert "Select one option" then it shows the results, any idea if you can see what's wrong, thank you . 
https://codepen.io/beh4r/pen/joPmKd

Comment: Hey Behar. The problem is that you're 'abusing' the validateForm() function to check if the user selected the correct answers. Unfortunately this fucntion just checks if the user selected an answer at all. I recommend setting up an additional array userAnswer and inside validateForm() at this line `if (radios[i].checked)` populate the array with the‪ selected answer like `userAnswer.push(radios[i].value);`Later on you can compare it to the answer array.

Comment: @obsecure - Hey man what's up and sorry bother you, but would you have time to check my thread about the same problem because I am stuck on this quiz and i still cannot solve the errors ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103602/submit-button-that-shows-the-score?noredirect=1#comment98841833_56103602