# Submit button that shows the score

Tags: javascript

Below it's my code with a quiz of 4 questions and with a "Submit" button in the last question and I tried to add some code that on Submit it will show an alert with the results of the quiz about how many questions I got correct.
But there are some errors with my code that when I press Submit it doesn't show results of the quiz and it still shows me "Select an option", even that I've selected an option from the question and I've added an if statement to Submit button so it will check if any option is selected or not, but even If I select any option it still shows me that alert ?

```js
let question1 = document.getElementById('pytja1');
let question2 = document.getElementById('pytja2');
let question3 = document.getElementById('pytja3');
let question4 = document.getElementById('pytja4');
let result = document.getElementById('bot-submit');
let nextButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.bot');

for (let i = 0; i < nextButtons.length; i++) {
  let nextQuestion = nextButtons[i];
  nextQuestion.onclick = function() {

    if (validateForm(i + 1)) {
      switchToNextQuestion(this);
    }
  }
}

function switchToNextQuestion(nextQuestion) {
  let parentId = nextQuestion.parentNode.id;
  if (parentId === 'pytja1') {
    question1.style.display = 'none';
    question2.style.display = 'block';
  } else if (parentId === 'pytja2') {
    question2.style.display = 'none';
    question3.style.display = 'block';
  } else if (parentId === 'pytja3') {
    question3.style.display = 'none';
    question4.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function validateForm(elementNumber) { // elementnumber gets radio name from multiple questions
  let radios = document.getElementsByName("q" + elementNumber);
  let formValid = false;
  let i = 0;
  while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
    if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
    i++;
  }
  if (!formValid) alert("Select one option");
  return formValid;
}

let questions = [{
    question: "I am a ?",
    userAnswers: ["Male", "Female", "Other"],
    correctAnswers: 0,
  },
  {
    question: "Football has letters ?",
    userAnswers: [8, 5, 6],
    correctAnswers: 0,
  },
  {
    question: "VW stands for ?",
    userAnswers: ["BMW", "Volkswagen", "Audi"],
    correctAnswers: 1,
  },
  {
    question: "What year is it ?",
    userAnswers: [2017, 2015, 2019],
    correctAnswers: 2,
  }
];

function submitAnswer(elementNumber) {
  let radios = document.getElementsByName("q" + elementNumber);
  let formValid = false;
  let i = 0;
  while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
    if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
    i++;
  }
  if (!formValid) alert("Select one option");
  return formValid;

  for (i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    let correctAnswerIndex = questions[i].correctAnswers;
    if (correctAnswerIndex === userAnswers[i]) {
      score++;
    }
  }

  if (score != total) {
    alert("You got " + score + " out " + total)
  }
  if (score === total) {
    alert("Congratulation your score " + score + " out of " + total);
  }
  let results = document.getElementById('results')
  alert("you")
}
document.getElementById("bot-submit").addEventListener("click",
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  })
```

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.quiz {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 42%;
}

.quest1,
.quest2,
.quest3,
.quest4 {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.questions1 {
  margin-left: 28px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.questions2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.questions3 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.questions4 {
  background-color: olivedrab;
}

.bot {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#pytja2,
#pytja3,
#pytja4 {
  margin-left: 28px;
  display: none;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form id="quiz-form">
  <div di="results"></div>
  <div class="quiz">
    <div id="pytja1" class="questions1">
      <span class="quest1">I am a ?</span><br/>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="male" id="correct"> Male<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="female" id="correct2"> Female<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="other" id="correct3"> Other<br/>
      <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" "/>
          </div>
          <div id="pytja2 " class="questions2 ">
            <span class="quest2 ">Football has letters ?</span><br/>
            <input type="radio " name="q2 " value="8 " class="correct "> 8<br/>
            <input type="radio " name="q2 " value="5 "> 5<br/>
            <input type="radio " name="q2 " value="6 "> 6<br/>
            <input class="bot " type="button " value="Next ""/>
    </div>
    <div id="pytja3" class="questions3">
      <span class="quest3">VW stands for ?</span><br/>
      <input type="radio" name="q3" value="BMW" /> BMW <br/>
      <input type="radio" name="q3" value="Volkswagen" class="correct" /> Volkswagen<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="q3" value="Audi" /> Audi<br/>
      <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" "/>
          </div>
          <div id="pytja4 " class="questions4 ">
            <span class="quest4 ">What year we are ?</span><br/>
            <input type="radio " name="q4 " value="2017 " /> 2017<br/>
            <input type="radio " name="q4 " value="2015 " /> 2015<br/>
            <input type="radio " name="q4 " value="2019 " class="correct " /> 2019<br/>
            <input id="bot-submit " type="submit " value="Submit " onclick="submitAnswer(); "/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Your example code has a number of typos that cause error messages. You should clean those up first.

Comment: `"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 193,
  "colno": 38`

Comment: Everything in the ` submitAnswer(elementNumber)` function from the `for` loop downward is unreachable code as you have it due to the `return formValid;`

Comment: I added that code in submitAnswer function so it would look if any option is checked on the last question before pressing Submit button because on validateForm have a loop code then added the same code on submitAnswer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, your code has some errors but I have written snippets that will achieve your aim with shorter syntax.

```js
//Javascript code
let questionss = [{
    question: "I am a ?",
    options: ["Male", "Female", "Other"],
    correctAnswers: 'Male',
  },
  {
    question: "Football has letters ?",
    options: [8, 5, 6],
    correctAnswers: 8,
  },
  {
    question: "VW stands for ?",
    options: ["BMW", "Volkswagen", "Audi"],
    correctAnswers: 'Volkswagen',
  },
  {
    question: "What year is it ?",
    options: [2017, 2015, 2019],
    correctAnswers: 2019,
  }
];

let questionText = document.getElementById('cd-questions');
let optiontext = document.querySelectorAll('.optiontext');
let options = document.querySelectorAll('.options');
let nextBtn = document.getElementById('next-btn');
let currentQuestion = 0;
var score = 0;
var checkedStatus = false;


setQuestion(currentQuestion); // set default question

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (valForm()) setQuestion(currentQuestion); //validates and next question
});

function setQuestion(currentQuestion) {
  questionText.innerText = questionss[currentQuestion].question; //set current question to the DOM

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    options[i].value = questionss[currentQuestion].options[i]; //set options  value for current question

    optiontext[i].innerText = questionss[currentQuestion].options[i]; //set options for current question

  }
}

function valForm() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (options[i].checked) {
      let userans = options[i].value;
      if (questionss[currentQuestion].correctAnswers == userans) {
        score++;
      }

      options[i].checked = false;
      if (currentQuestion < questionss.length - 1) {

        currentQuestion++;
        if (currentQuestion == questionss.length - 1) {
          nextBtn.innerText = 'Submit';
        }
      } else {
        alert('Your total score is ' + score);
        currentQuestion = 0;
        nextBtn.innerText = 'Start';
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
  if (checkedStatus == false) {
    alert('please choose an answer');
    setQuestion(currentQuestion);
  }

  return false;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="cd-questions"></div>
  <input class="options" name="answer" type="radio" />
  <span class="optiontext"></span>
  <input class="options" name="answer" type="radio" />
  <span class="optiontext"></span>
  <input class="options" name="answer" type="radio" />
  <span class="optiontext"></span>
  <div>
    <button id="next-btn">Next</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot finally it's working :) And just a question about "for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {" would you explain to me what you added 3 there? You wrote that to increment  because there are 3 questions and another question is validated with the button Next or what, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy it worked. I want to believe your other question is from the second loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
if (options[i].checked) { //iterates through the radio buttons for the checked option
  let userans = options[i].value; // get the value of the checked 
  if (questionss[currentQuestion].correctAnswers == userans) {
    score++; //increment score by 1 if the chosen answer is the correct answer
  }
  options[i].checked = false; //reset button to avoid next question being checked by 
  default.
  if (currentQuestion < questionss.length - 1) {

    currentQuestion++; // increment current question index
    if (currentQuestion == questionss.length - 1) {
      nextBtn.innerText = 'Submit'; // Changed submit button text if it's the last question.
    }
  } else {
    alert('Your total score is ' + score);
    currentQuestion = 0;
    nextBtn.innerText = 'Start';
  }
  return true; // return true which was  tested when the function was involked before nexting the question.
}
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot again and thanks for putting a comment there to comment your code :)